# generate a multidimensional hash which contains one key and two values associated with that key

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, multidimensional-array

I am trying to generate a multidimensional hash which contains one key and two values associated with that key. Here is my sample input file

```
layer_def A1 10001;

layer_map 2 -datatype 2 10001;



layer_def A2 10002;

layer_map 3 -datatype 2 10002;
```

I want to compare the last element( 2nd pattern ) of first line with the last element( 3rd pattern ) of second line(i.e 10001 with 10001 ) and if they are equal then pick the first pattern of first line and 1 & 2nd patterns from second line and push them into a hash whose key will be Ist pattern of first line and the values will be 1st & 2nd patters from second line. And later want to use this hash to generate an output format like

Expected sample output

```
A1 = layer( 2 type(2))
A2 = layer( 3 type(2))
```

I tried with following sample code but seems like, we can't assign multi values to a single key.

```
sample perl code..

#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict();
my $inFile = shift @ARGV;
my %cdnsInt=();
my %layerInfo=();
my %outHash=();

open layerMap, $inFile or die "can't read $inFile \n";
while(my $line = <layerMap>) {
  if( $line =~ /^\s*layer_map\s+(\S+)\s+-datatype\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*;/gi ) {
    %layerInfo = ( $3 => [$1, $2]);
  } elsif($line =~ /^\s*layer_def\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*;/gi ) {
    $cdnsInt{$2}=$1;
  }
}

for ( keys %layerInfo ) {
   for my $tmp ( keys %cdnsInt ) {
    if ( $_  eq $tmp )  {
      push @{ $outHash{values %cdnsInt} }, (values %layerInfo );
    }
   }
}
```

Could somebody please help me this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards,
Divesh

Answer (score 1):

This resets your hash from scratch for each line:

```
%layerInfo = ( $3 => [$1, $2]);
```

Try instead:

```
$layerInfo{$3}= [ $1, $2 ] ;
```

Better yet, if you want to get closer to the final result faster on the same line as the `layerInfo` assigment do:

```
$outHash{cdnsInt{$3}}= [ $1, $2 ] ;
```

This gets you:

```
$outHash = {
          'A1' => [
                    '2',
                    '2'
                  ],
          'A2' => [
                    '3',
                    '2'
                  ]
        };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot woolstar. How can I retrieve the values from outHash now?

Comment: `$outHash{'A1'}[0]` & `$outHash{'A1'}[1]`